# How to loop the ul inside ul in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is this correct implementing the wordpress loop in parent ul and child ul?
i have some problem because the parent  is output correctly, but the child  is not . the post title of the child  is outputed in one parent ul only.

```
<ul class="multi-category">

<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => array('post'),'posts_per_page' => 3)); ?>
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>   

    <li>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Food</a></h3>
        <div class="multi-category-image">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Fun creations with potatoes and rice">
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail(420,470);
                            } else { ?>
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                            <?php } ?></a>
                            <div class="multi-category-text">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            </div><!--multi-category-text-->
        </div><!--multi-category-image-->
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                    <?php endif; ?> 



                    <div class="multi-category-headlines">
            <ul class="multi-category-headlines">
                    <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => array('post'),'posts_per_page' => 4)); ?>
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                                </ul>

        </div><!--multi-category-headlines-->
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What do you want to do exactly, parse this or generate this?

Comment: what is the problem you're having?

Comment: im confused how to insert the loop in my parent <ul class="multi-category"> and and my child <ul class="multi-category-headlines"> in wordpress post

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `query_posts`. [It messes up the wordpress loop.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Use [Wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead:

```
( ..parent loop .. ..the_title()..etc )

$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => 10,
    'post_type'       => 'my-post-type',
    'post_status'     => 'publish' );

$myloop = new WP_Query($args);  //<-- do the query for my subloop

//  Now use the $myloop to form the subloop
//  In loop you can forget $myloop and juse just the wordpress template tags like in 
//  the main loop.
if ( $myloop->have_posts() ): while ( $myloop->have_posts() ) : $myloop->the_post();
     the_title();    // <-- wordpress now knows it's for the $myloop loop  
endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();  //<<-- return to the main loop. don't forget it


( ..parent loop .. )
```

Hope this helps. See the codex. It's really simple.

Comment: how about the child loop post ? <ul class="multi-category-headlines">

Comment: I'm not shure what do you mean. To get some post's childs you must pass a parent's id to the query. But i think posts are not hierachical in wordpress. Pages are. Are these pages ?